# Pull-up resistor

Tags: resistors, brushless-dc-motor, driver, mosfet-driver, pullup

I am making a BLDC motor controller , so can you tell me the use of pullup resistor connected in the feedback of hall sensor.And is HO is equal to VB voltage when driver circuit operates ? Please explain the value of phase output voltage coming ( Explain any phase voltage).[image]

Comment: How can we read the datasheet to tell you the pull-up value if you don't tell us which part it is?

Comment: I only want to know the use of this pullup resistor

Comment: Maybe the outputs are open collector?  Hard to say without a datasheet!

Answer (score 1):

Circuits with pullups generally pull down the voltage sharply to ground then let go, relying on the pullup resistor R to pull the voltage high. How quickly it can pull the voltage up is a function of R and any capacitance on the line.

If the sensor signal is changing so quickly that the pullup doesn’t have time to pull the voltage up between transitions then you have a problem. This limits the upper bound of R.

The lower bound of R is dictated by how much current the sensor driver can sink, which is a function of its output impedance.

Lacking any specifications of your sensor device, R=1K is a good place to start.

Comment: Lower limit of R is also dependent on the supply current available for it.